# Cant connect remotelly to MySQL Server from DigitalOcean

Tags: mysql, nginx, remote

I've just finished setting up my Server on Digital Ocean (Ubuntu 12.10 x64) using nginx, but i want a separate MySQL Server to decrease the load to the web server.

The problem is, im unable to connect to my server.

I've tried to setup iptables to open port 3306,
I've commented the line bind-address
The server works fine locally, tested with wordpress, nginx and phpmyadmin.

I cant connect from anywhere, keep getting ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '192.XXX.XXX.XXX' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.

And yes i reloaded all services all the times...

Comment: Im so sorry, but im not familiar using MySQL by SSH and i did not understood this command very well... Maybe i could get the info on PhpMyAdmin? Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `ERROR 1130` MySQL error is a grant issue within MySQL.  That you're getting this is *good news* - your remote host (let's call it `R1`) is connecting to your MySQL host (`My1`).  `My1` is checking against it's `GRANT` table and sees that you're not allowed to connect to the database you'd like to as the user you're trying from that remote host (`R1`).

You need to add a new [GRANT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) to allow the connection.

To see existing grants connect to MySQL as root on `My1` (`mysql -u root -p mysql`) and then run:

```
SELECT host,user FROM user;
```

Comment: This is most likely the issue. To put it simple: Most users are added as a local account only, 'user'@'localhost' and they would need to be added via GRANT with the mask 'user'@'192.xxx.xxx.xxx'

Comment: On this MySQL server im using the root user to manage my DBs.... should i work with it or create a new user? And if i create a new user shal i include it in some group?

Comment: To connect to `My1` from `R1` you're connecting using a username and password (it won't be root... or, at least, I *shouldn't be*).  You need to `ssh` to `My1` login to MySQL (as above) and `GRANT` that user access from the IP of `R1` (see the link in my answer).  I can't give you much more without knowing schema, user and IP - which I don't recommend you publicly share.

Comment: It is funny, i just created a new user from PhpMyAdmin panel and granted him permissions and now, using this username, the connection works! Thank you very much!